# Azure Service Fabric its purpose of different Services

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Azure Service Fabric whats the purpose of  different Services ,please give with examples and also step by step process for deployment

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take a look at the service fabric documentation.

Supported services
- [Reliable Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction), [Reliable Actors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction), [Guest Executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app)

Deployment - [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications), [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-publish-app-remote-cluster)